# php password_verify function doesn't matching

Tags: php, hash, passwords, verify

I want use password_verify to login, and this is my code

```
$DB1->select('Idx,Email,Password');
$DB1->from('User');
$DB1->where('Email',$Email);
$result = $DB1->get()->result();
// get_where('4SUser',array('Email' => $Email))->result();

if(password_verify($this->input->post('Password'), $result[0]->Password)) {
    $this->response("Login Success");
} else {
    $this->response("Login Failed");
}
```

And then, this is when I join the member use password_hash

---update change
    $hash = password_hash($this->input->post('Password'), PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

I don't know why it returns error;

use password tester1234 and in DB, $2y$10$FZ7WV5cn5OL58t5hgM3cBeb2NRfXk7IrxNzyBiBMYZA.HYtXSSDjS

this is DB value.

But when I test hash_password when I input the password,

```
"$2y$10$KP1MG1abyMBD/gR82WmKoONvW/VvblYix13We6MNeRKdbDg0ufRQC"
"$2y$10$2H7Lx340yXWBFXFgv2LUJuN.luODBmJtNwfrCVQh2A37O0Es9Ud/K"
"$2y$10$.xUl/0zKnt.m26MSVwUBDOFVx29Bd8XxNyI.t7RqonfP8pmwIIVRC"
```

Every Time changes

Is it cause the error of doesn't match the password?

please help me

---update question

```
$HashInputPassword = password_hash($this->input->post('Password'), PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$UserPassword = $result[0]->Password;

if($HashInputPassword === $UserPassword) {
    $this->response("Login Success");
} else {
    $this->response("Login Failed");
}
```

Comment: Every time you call `password_hash` it will be different because the salt changes.

Comment: You call `password_hash` to create the hash and store that, and then you call `password_verify` to see if they match.

Comment: @Augwa Yes I did and update my question, it was success when I call $HashInputPassword but it was failed when I called in DB.
In my DB, column Password type is varchar255 and not null.

Comment: You have `$this->input->post('Password')` is password suppose to be capitalized?

Comment: @Augwa when input 
$Password = $this->input->post('Password');

Comment: Your html form, is password called `Password` or `password` it's case sensitive.

Comment: @Augwa It called Password

Comment: You're 100% sure? You called it `password`, somewhere else in your code. Did you verify what PHP is seeing for `$this->input->post('Password')`?

Comment: @Augwa Thanks your suggestion is right. I change the password to Password in second chapter, issue is disappear. Thanks